# Why is Uri a class and not a struct?

Tags: c#, .net

`System.Uri` seems to be a perfect candidate for being a `struct` but the good folks at Microsoft decided to make it a `class`. It is clearly a value object -> there is no sense in having two different *instances* of "https://stackoverflow.com" and so it has struct-y equality rules. I can't see any setters on the public API either, so it is immutable.

Is there some implementation detail which dictates it must be a `class`?

Comment: This is actually a question for code review not stackoverflow, but to answer it: Uri is not just a string, the string is analysed and the uri class has quite a lot of variables, you don't want to copy that every time.

Comment: `System.Uri` contains 7 fields, each of which would be the size of a reference. That's too much for a struct (in terms of performance).

Comment: @FelixK. [other people's code is not appropriate for codereview se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: To add, the MS guidelines on when to use a struct say to avoid structs with a size > 16 bytes. As others have said, Uri is quite a bit bigger than this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct

Comment: `so it has struct-y equality rules` A class can implement `struct-y` equality rules if it so chooses.

Comment: @FelixK. I don't see anything about this question that would make it off-topic for Stack Overflow. You don't have to have a *problem* to ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `struct` would always have a default constructor (where all fields would be initialized to their default values). This could cause issues, for example, with some of the internal fields.

One example is that the existing constructor **ensures** that `m_String` can't be null - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/UriExt.cs,39 . If you made this a struct, you can't easily achieve that in C#. So, everywhere you read from `m_String` you'd need to add a `null` check (which is not required if it is a class).

Additionally, as others have pointed out, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) have other guidance on choosing when to use `struct`:

> ✓ CONSIDER defining a struct instead of a class if instances of the
>   type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in
>   other objects.
>
> X AVOID defining a struct unless the type has all of the following
>   characteristics:
>
> It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types
>   (int, double, etc.).
>
> It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
>
> It is immutable.
>
> It will not have to be boxed frequently.

The 16 byte requirement, in particular, is likely to be problematic for `Uri`.